The existence of such homomorphism
Are there any papers or books that investigate/discuss the relationship between conjugacy classes and normality for the existence of non-trivial homomrphism f:G->H were H is some nontrivial subgroup of G

Every group has at least one abelian subgroup. Is that what you meant to write?

Groups with every subgroup normal are called Dedekind groups, and they have been classified.  See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_group

@AndyPutman
In there investigating on Dedekind group they didn't discuss the existence of the homomorphism that I'm looking for.

@DerekHolt
I correct the qustion now

@Naif: I'm not inclined to do your work for you, but from the classification it should either be trivially true or trivially false.
